# Galois group of quartic polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

> Let $f(x)$ be a quartic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know that the following facts:

1. If $f(x)$ is separable over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the Galois group $G_{f}$ of $f(x)$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_{4}$.
2. $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $G_{f}$ is isomorphic to a transitive subgroup of the symmetric group $S_{4}$.

What can we say about that the Galois group for an arbitrary quartic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Some problem claims that if $f(x)$ is a quartic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with splitting field $K$ satisfying $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=8$, then $G_{f}\cong D_{4}$, where $D_{4}$ is the dihedral group of order $8$.

I think we need the condition separability or irreducibility of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is needed, but there's nothing like that.

Do I miss something or have a misconception? Give some advice or comments. Thank you!

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718061/determining-galois-group-of-polynomial-of-degree-4?rq=1) and similar posts!

Comment: @DietrichBurde In that post, the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Do you mean by the degree $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=8$ is the key?

Comment: [Here](https://planetmath.org/galoisgroupofaquarticpolynomial) is a discussion of all quartic polynomials, also reducible ones, and their Galois groups.